# Consulta mysql que lleva un limit dentro de un while

Tags: php, mysql

quisiera saber si se puede limitar una consulta mysql con variables  php
algo asi

```
while($i<=100){
$i+5;
$consulta = $con->consulta("SELECT  * FROM  ver_asignaciones limit $i,$i ");
}
```

y que la $i que esta dentro de la consulta de mysql sea 5, 10 luego 11,16, y así sucesivamente

Comment: Sí, se puede. Es más, por qué no has probado tu código? Ahí verías que efectivamente, la consulta usa el limit que le pongas al construir la consulta

Comment: ya lo probé y el problema esta en que la variable $i se mantiene como 5,5 y yo quiero que se a 5, 10 y luego 10, 15 y así en el limit

Comment: Pues entonces crea otra variable $j y le vas asignando el i+5, luego usas las dos variables $i, $j y listo.

Comment: no deberia ser $i=$i+5? si no, donde le asignas el valor a la variable?

Comment: Debes tomar en cuenta que LIMIT <número_inicia_extraer>, <número_cantidad_extraer>, Es decir si quieres obtener los primeros 10 registros y despues los siguientes 10 seria mas o menos así: SELECT * FROM <tabla> LIMIT 0,10; SELECT * FROM <tabla> LIMIT 10, 10; y así sucesivamente. El primer valor seria el cambiante (variable).